# Can't reach database server at `aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

Happy Monday! I've recently run into a weird issue and can't seem to figure out what would be causing it.

I have a NextJS project using Prisma and Supabase. When I run the app on my Windows desktop or Vercel, it runs perfectly with no error. However, when I run it on my MacBook, it presents me with this error:

```
Error: 
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:


Can't reach database server at `aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com`:`5432`.
Source
src/app/layout.tsx (37:17) @ async getData
  35 | noStore();
  36 | if (userId) {
> 37 |   const data = await prisma.user.findUnique({
     |               ^
  38 |     where: {
  39 |       id: userId,
  40 |     },
```

I've looked around for some answers but can't seem to find anyone with the same problem, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check the docs: https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma

Answer (score 3):

Get Transaction and Session connection pooler string from your Superbase database setting page.

Transaction connection pooler string:

```
postgres://[db-user].[project-ref]:[db-password]@aws-0-[aws-region].pooler.supabase.com:6543/[db-name]?pgbouncer=true&connection_limit=1
```

Session connection pooler string:

```
postgres://[db-user].[project-ref]:[db-password]@aws-0-[aws-region].pooler.supabase.com:5432/[db-name]
```

Update .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="" #The Transaction connection pooler string
DIRECT_URL=""  #The Session connection pooler string
```

schema.prisma file should look like:

```
datasource db {
 provider          = "postgresql"
 url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
 directUrl         = env("DIRECT_URL")
}
```

From [Superbase document](https://supabase.com/partners/integrations/prisma)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me in the connection string for `directUrl = env("DIRECT_DATABASE_URL")`.

```
-DIRECT_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@db.[project-ref].supabase.co:5432/postgres
+DIRECT_DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres.[project-ref]:[YOUR-PASSWORD]@aws-0-eu-central-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres
```